# How to compute (unipotent) radicals?

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

My question follows some previous one, essentially [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38365/questions-about-unipotent-radical). I want to understand, given an algebraic group $G$ (say linear), how to compute its radical and unipotent radical. The (unipotent) radical is the maximal connected normal solvable (unipotent) subgroup of $G$ by definition.

By the Lie-Kolchin theorem, we know that a connected solvable closed subgroup is conjugate to a subgroup of block upper triangular matrices. Since the radicals are normal subgroups, they are made of block upper triangular matrices.

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
A_1 & \star & \star & \star \\
& A_2 & \star & \star \\
& & \ddots & \star \\
& & & A_r
\end{array}
 \right)$$

Then I suppose it is possible to understand case by case who are exactly the such subgroups, writing down explicitly the conditions for belonging to the group $G$.

However, how to determine the sizes of the blocks given in the Lie-Kolchin theorem? Typically, for the case of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ they are known to be one and symmetries arguments show that the unipotent radical is trivial. What about other groups, for instance $\mathrm{GSp}(4)$ or a small unitary group?

Comment: "*By the Lie-Kolchin theorem, we know that a connected solvable closed subgroup is conjugate to a subgroup of block upper triangular matrices*" sounds senseless. Every subgroup is block upper triangular matrices. You need to say more to make this statement non-void. Also such statements about algebraic groups should be more carefully stated with explicit reference to the ground field. For the same reason the sentence "*Since the radicals are normal subgroups, they are made of block upper triangular matrices*" makes little sense.

Comment: Over a characteristic zero field (which I assume is the case as you mentioned Lie-Kolchin), every reductive group has trivial unipotent radical, so things like GSp4 or unitary group will have trivial unipotent radical. Also then radical is just the connected component of the center.